# What is the sIgnificance of equator in GPS offset calculation?

Tags: gps, offset

I am going through a SAE document where it says that the GPS offsets (NodeLL) should be calculated in such a way that the range should be within one of these:

```
ranges of +- 0.0008191 degrees
ranges of +- 90.571389 meters at the EQUATOR
```

The way it is calculated in the code written was just a mere subtraction of latitudes and longitudes. If this is correct what is the significance of `equator` here? Or is there anything wrong we are doing?